# Start a Cronjob if another ends?

Tags: php, cron, crontrigger

I have 7 cron-jobs which must be run in a specified order!

So I must call them in order. But my problem is, how can I trigger the next cronjob if my last cronjob finished?

I want to write me a script which triggers every cronjob but to trigger the next one I need to know if my last cronjob has ended.

I prefer **PHP**.

Comment: It sounds like you only need 1 cronjob that includes 7 scripts.

Comment: if they have to run in a predefined order, wouldn't it be much smarter to join them into *one* script?

Comment: the quickest way (and hackish) if you don't have many cron jobs is to list them in the corntab using semicolons like so: "* * * * * cron1_command;cron2_command >> /ptah/to/log.txt"

Comment: I want to write one script which is triggering the other scripts. But I can not bundle them because one 4 cronjobs are plugins in WordPress and my 3 other cronjobs are by my hoster

Comment: I guess the 3 cronjobs for the hoster are running from a different username?

Comment: No! - But I can start them only in the interface

Answer (score 0):

either create a shell script or do something like this:

```
0 */5 * * * php /var/www/html/project1/cron.php && php /var/www/html/project2/cron.php && php /var/www/html/project3/cron.php
```

If you want a php script to do work for you and record its output, do stuff like this

```
ini_set('memory_limit','8196M');
$date=date('mdY');
if(!file_exists($date."_ENK.zip"))
{
echo "sh get_files.sh ".$date."_ENK.zip\n";
echo "DOWNLOADING FILE\n";
echo popen("sh get_files.sh ".$date."_ENK.zip >> get_log",'r');
echo "MOVING FILE\n";
echo exec("mv ".$date.".csv ../../data/data.csv");
echo "IMPORTING INTO DATABASE\n";
echo exec("php /var/www/html/project1/index.php Engines dothings");
echo "DUMPING INTO TEMP FOLDER\n";
echo exec("mysqldump -u user db tab > /tmp/tab.sql");
echo "UPDATING\n";
echo exec("mysql -u far_user -ppass -h 10.0.0.1 db_away < /tmp/tab.sql");
echo "CLEANING UP";
echo exec("rm -f /tmp/tab.sql");
echo exec("rm -f ../../data/data.csv");
echo exec("rm -f somefile.zip");
}
```